# How Create Windows instance password without pem key

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passwords

How Set password Windows instance aws without a key pair

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched from a provided Windows AMI, there is a utility installed on the disk that will generate a **random Administrator password**. This is done to prevent other people from being able to login and control your computer.

To allow you to know this password, the utility encrypts the password with the Keypair selected on startup. The encrypted password is then provided back via the *System Log* (which appears on-screen during the boot sequence). The EC2 management console then lets you decrypt this password by supplying the matching keypair.

Once you initially access the instance, you are welcome (and encouraged!) to change the password connect it to an Active Directory server. Also, if an image (AMI) is created from this computer, the password will remain the same.

Alternatively, you can use a **User Data script** that executes at startup. You could write a script in PowerShell that changes the password to a pre-defined password. Something like this (I did not test it):

```sh
<powershell>
net user Administrator "new_password"
</powershell>
```

See: [Set the password for a Windows instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html)

Comment: I know all of this
But I don't want a random password
I want to set a static password for all instances

Comment: First, that's not a great idea from a security standpoint. It would be better to use Active Directory to use authentication across instances. Secondly, if you are booting an instance for the first time, you can use a User Data script (as explained above) to set a specific password. Please note that this password will be visible in the User Data associated with the instance, so it's not a good idea for security either. Or, you can use the AMI method explained above so that all instances are launched with a static password.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not understand you well
Can you simplify it in steps?
How to set a static password before creating an instance
The evidence above is not helpful

For example if there is code that can be placed inside (UserData) while creating an instance
It will be very useful

Comment: I added an example, but haven't tested it. You can't set a password "before" launching the instance, but this script will run after the first boot. However, people might be able to view this script in the EC2 console if they have sufficient permissions, so the password would be exposed.